# Ubuntu postgresql missing man pages, PGDATA, and critical commands

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

I installed postgresql as well as postgresql-doc, nevertheless it seems that ubuntu either does not put commands in my path, or if it does put them in my path, it removes the man pages for the corresponding command. There is some logic that ensures that if a command is in the path, the man page is not, or vice versa.  Not sure if this is a joke, error, or both:

to wit:

```
postgres@ubuntu:~$ man pg_ctl  #this works!
postgres@ubuntu:~$ which pg_ctl #not in my path

postgres@ubuntu:~$ man psql
No manual entry for psql
See 'man 7 undocumented' for help when manual pages are not available.

postgres@ubuntu:~$ which psql  #command is my path!
/usr/bin/psql
```

This is the same for whether I log in as my regular user or as the postgres user.

Anyone know how to get ubuntu to install both commands and man pages for the commands?

For the life of me, I can't find where the $PGDATA dir is, either. I would install postgres by source, but a package will notify me of updates. I looked on ubuntu's wiki (a single page) and couldn't find anything that talked about man pages, paths, or PGDATA. Am on ubuntu 12.10

Comment: [To find the data directory](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8237512/562459). This question will probably be closed as being off-topic.

Comment: Just run `apt-get install postgresql-client`

Answer (score 1):

The server-side commands are under `/usr/lib/postgresql/X.Y/bin` so that multiple major versions can be installed in parallel.  Normally, you don't actually need to call these directly.  For example, instead of `pg_ctl` you could call `pg_ctlcluster` (see its man page).  See the documentation under `/usr/share/doc/postgresql-common/` for details.  (If you wanted to, you could put `/usr/lib/postgresql/X.Y/bin` into your path, of course.)